# Write a shell script that will return the list of files skipped by your repository git

Tags: bash, git, shell

I would love some help to write a shell script that will return the list of files skipped by my git repository.

There is an example code below

```
%> bash git_ignore.sh | cat -e
.DS_Store$
mywork.c~$
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+ignored+files

Answer (score 4):

To list all ignored files you can try

```
find . -type f  | git check-ignore --stdin
```

EDIT:

- `find . -type f` find all files in current directory and any sub-directories.
- `git check-ignore` check if a file is excluded by gitignore.

In this case will all files in current directory, and any sub-directories, be feed to check-ignore and any file that are excluded by gitignore will be printed out.